# Discord.py client.say doesn't work in an event loop task

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm using discord.py for a bot and I'm trying to make a setup function run in the background while other functions run as well. It seems to be working but the program stops at the client.say (prints a but not b). I don't get any error either.

```
async def setup():
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Setting game up...',colour=0xff66ff)
    print('a')
    setupmsg = await client.say(embed=embed)
    print('b')
    #send message for each person
    for i in USER_LIST:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{i.name}",colour=0xff66ff)
        msg = await client.say(embed=embed)
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u2705')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u274E')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u2754')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\U0001F31F')
    await client.delete_message(setupmsg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `await client.say()` outside of a `@client.command()` as per the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-bot-say-in-other-places-aside-from-commands)

You can try passing the message argument from the event to the coro and using `send_message()` instead

Something like

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author != client.user:
    await setup(message)

async def setup(message):
  USER_LIST = message.server.members
  embed = discord.Embed(title='Setting game up...',colour=0xff66ff)
  print('a')
  setupmsg = await client.send_message(message.channel,embed=embed)
  print('b')
  #send message for each person
  for i in USER_LIST:
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{i.name}",colour=0xff66ff)
    msg = await client.send_message(message.channel,embed=embed)
    await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u2705')
    await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u274E')
    await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u2754')
    await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\U0001F31F')
  await client.delete_message(setupmsg)
```